How to make a PaginatedDataTable have two scroll bars vertical and horizontal on Flutter web?
I have a paginated data table and I'm trying to make it scrollable with scrollbars on Flutter web vertical and horizontal.
Like this: Two directional scrollbar

I managed to make it work to a degree with this code :
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _verticalScrollController = ScrollController();
  final _horizontalScrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Data Table'),
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        child: Scrollbar(
          thumbVisibility: true,
          controller: _verticalScrollController,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _verticalScrollController,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Scrollbar(
              scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.bottom,
              controller: _horizontalScrollController,
              child: PaginatedDataTable(
                header: const Text('Orders Table'),
                controller: _horizontalScrollController,
                columns: const [
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Sales Order')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Sold to Party')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Party Name')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Status')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Currency')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Order Type')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Creation Date')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Total Net Amount')),
                ],
                source: _DataSource(data: sampleOrders),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Now it shows the vertical scrollbar but the horizontal one doesn't show unless I scroll with my trackpad first then it shows up and can be used, but this wouldn't work on a pc (bcs of no trackpad) and I want it visible from the start so the user knows that it can be scrolled and if possible, have the bottom scrollbar pinned so it can be visible without scrolling down.
I think part of the problem is that PaginatedDataTable has some kind of scrolling mechanic in it whether I put a scrollbar or not.
I tried other stack overflow solutions but they ended up either with errors or the same result.
How can I fix this?
